# How does DelegatingVehicleTracker (p. 65 Goetz) return a "live" view?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, delegation

On page 65 and 66 of Java Concurrency in Practice Brian Goetz lists the following code:

```
@ThreadSafe
public class DelegatingVehicleTracker {
private final ConcurrentMap<String, Point> locations;
private final Map<String, Point> unmodifiableMap;

public DelegatingVehicleTracker(Map<String, Point> points) {
    locations = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Point>(points);
    unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(locations);
}

public Map<String, Point> getLocations() {
    return unmodifiableMap;
}

public Point getLocation(String id) {
    return locations.get(id);
}

public void setLocation(String id, int x, int y) {
    if (locations.replace(id, new Point(x, y)) == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid vehicle name: " + id);
}

// Alternate version of getLocations (Listing 4.8)
public Map<String, Point> getLocationsAsStatic() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(
            new HashMap<String, Point>(locations));
}
}
```

About this class Goetz writes:

> "...the delegating version [the code above] returns an unmodifiable but 
>   'live' view of the vehicle locations. This means that if thread A calls
>   getLocations() and thread B later modifies the location of some of the 
>   points, those changes are reflected in the map returned to thread A."

In what sense would Thread A's unmodifiableMap be "live"? I do not see how changes made by Thread B via calls to setLocation() would be reflected in Thread A's unmodifiableMap. This would seem the case only if Thread A constructed a new instance of DelegatingVehicleTracker. But were Thread A to hold a reference to this class, I do not see how this is possible.

Goetz goes on to say that getLocationsAsStatic() could be called were an "unchanging view of the fleet required." I am confused. It seems to me that precisely the opposite is the case, that a call to getLocationsAsStatic() would indeed return the "live" view, and a call to getLocations(), were the class not constructed anew, would return the static, unchanging view of the fleet of cars.

What am I missing here in this example?

Any thoughts or perspectives are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your confusion is due to misunderstanding of `Collections.unmodifiableMap`. Direct mutation of the map returned by `Collections.unmodifiableMap` is not allowed, however, mutating the backing map is totally fine (as long as the backing map allows mutation).  For example:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);

map.put("key","value");

for (String key : unmodifiableMap.keySet()) {
   System.out.println(key); // prints key
}
```

So, `unmodifiableMap` in the `DelegatingVehicleTracker` example is backed by a mutable map `locations` (a `thread-safe` one). `setLocation` mutates `locations` atomically and hence changes will be visible for threads holding references to the `unmodifiableMap` knowing that those thread can't mutate the `unmodifiableMap`.
Readers don't have access to `locations` so mutating it will be done through `DelegatingVehicleTracker` only  and hence the name `delegation`.

Comment: Thanks Sleiman, and you others as well; now I get it. I'll spell it out to myself (of use hopefully to others): DelegatingVehicleTracker can modify, but client classes cannot. A call to unmodifiableMap in your example code above would throw an exception (I tried it out), but, of course, the insert to map does not. UnmodifiableMap is like a puppet show seen through a glass screen which bars the audience from meddling.

Comment: @BenWeaver there is a term for the metaphor you just described, it is delegation

Answer (score 1):

> In what sense would Thread A's unmodifiableMap be "live"? I do not see how changes made by Thread B via calls to setLocation() would be reflected in Thread A's unmodifiableMap

This is because `getLocations()` returns an unmodifiable wrapped map of the actual mutable map.

```
public DelegatingVehicleTracker(Map<String, Point> points) {
    locations = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Point>(points);
    unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(locations);
}
...

public Map<String, Point> getLocations() {
    return unmodifiableMap;
}
```

So any changes later will be automatically reflected in the original returned map since they both eventually point to the same internal Map object.

> Goetz goes on to say that getLocationsAsStatic() could be called were an "unchanging view of the fleet required"

This code

```
public Map<String, Point> getLocationsAsStatic() {
return Collections.unmodifiableMap(
        new HashMap<String, Point>(locations));
}
```

is static in the sense that future changes to `locations` are not reflected since it returns a new map with a copy of the all the current key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

`getLocations()` will return a **read-only** map which will reflect updates **after** `getLocations()` is called.

`getLocationsAsStatic()` on the other hand, will return a **read-only-snapshot** (aka deep copy) of the Location map at the time `getLocationsAsStatic()` is called.

To illustrate:

```
Map<String, Point> locs     = // a map with point A(1,1)  in it
DelegatingVehicleTracker tracker = DelegatingVehicleTracker(locs);

Map<String, Point> snapshot = getLocationsAsStatic();
Map<String, Point> live     = getLocations();

Point newB = // a point A(2,2)
tracker.setLocation(newB);

snapshot.get("A"); // will read A(1,1)
live.get("A");      // will read A(2,2)
```

Comment: thats actually the question, it is what the OP doesn't understand